# Is there any way to share generic type variables between classes?

Tags: generics, typescript

I would like to do something like this:

```
class B<X> {
  b_stuff: X;
  // etc...
}

// X is the same type as above
class A<X, Y> {

  a1_stuff: Y;
  a2_stuff: X;  
  // etc...
}
```

Is there any way to share type variables like this between classes? I thought nested classes would be the way to do this, but apparently TypeScript doesn't support this.

Comment: It doesn't make sense as it is, as `X` can be many things, it's not set. In inner classes there's a relationship between the containing and nested classes. Maybe you can explain more about your scenario so it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this; also it doesn't make any sense. There could be many `A` and `B` instances each instantiated with different type parameters. Try asking a different question where you approach the problem from the perspective of the code you're trying to write. It seems like you have an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but it is possible that your problem could be solved through inheritence:

```
public class List<E>{
....
}
public class ArrayList<E> implements List{
}
```

now when you make a list and an ArrayList out of that list they need to be the same type. for example:

```
public List<String> myList = new ArrayList(true, false, true, true)
```

you won't be allowed to create that list because they need to be the same type or at least implement the same type. (I say implement the same type because if you made a list of  then you could have an ArrayList, A LinkedList and a bunch of others) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: you can have a factory method in `A` which creates an instance of `B` bound to the same `X` as `A`:

```
class B<X> {
    b_stuff: X;
}

class A<X, Y> {
    a1_stuff: Y;
    a2_stuff: X;

    createB(...args: any[]): X {
        // create B using args
    }
}
```